Dynamic data source mapping in spring boot for data sharding
I am creating a spring boot application which will store data in Postgres. I have 3 Postgres instance which I am calling shard-0 shard-1 and shard-2, based on the shard key, I want to calculate and set datasource dynamically so that data will be stored in correct shard.
I am able to do it when I create a record, but when I try to retrieve it fails.
package com.zinu.account_manager.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.PrePersist;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "driver")
public class Driver implements Serializable{
@Id
private String id;
private String name;
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;
@Column(unique = true)
private String phoneNumber;
private Date createdAt;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "driver", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Cab> cabs = new ArrayList<>();
private Double currentLatitude;
private Double currentLongitude;
private String segmentId;
private int shardId;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    createdAt = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public List<Cab> getCabs() {
    return cabs;
}

public void setCabs(List<Cab> cabs) {
    this.cabs = cabs;
}

public Double getCurrentLatitude() {
    return currentLatitude;
}

public void setCurrentLatitude(Double currentLatitude) {
    this.currentLatitude = currentLatitude;
}

public Double getCurrentLongitude() {
    return currentLongitude;
}

public void setCurrentLongitude(Double currentLongitude) {
    this.currentLongitude = currentLongitude;
}

public String getSegmentId() {
    return segmentId;
}

public void setSegmentId(String segmentId) {
    this.segmentId = segmentId;
}

public int getShardId() {
    return shardId;
}

public void setShardId(int shardId) {
    this.shardId = shardId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Driver [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber
            + ", createdAt=" + createdAt + ", cabs=" + cabs + ", currentLatitude=" + currentLatitude
            + ", currentLongitude=" + currentLongitude + ", segmentId=" + segmentId + ", shardId=" + shardId
            + ", getId()=" + getId() + ", getName()=" + getName() + ", getEmail()=" + getEmail()
            + ", getPhoneNumber()=" + getPhoneNumber() + ", getCreatedAt()=" + getCreatedAt() + ", getCabs()="
            + getCabs() + ", getCurrentLatitude()=" + getCurrentLatitude() + ", getCurrentLongitude()="
            + getCurrentLongitude() + ", getSegmentId()=" + getSegmentId() + ", getShardId()=" + getShardId()
            + ", getClass()=" + getClass() + ", hashCode()=" + hashCode() + ", toString()=" + super.toString()
            + "]";
}



}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.zinu.account_manager", transactionManagerRef = "transcationManager", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@DependsOn("dataSourceRouting")
public class DataSourceConfig {

private final DataSourceRouting dataSourceRouting;
private final Environment env;

public DataSourceConfig(DataSourceRouting dataSourceRouting, Environment env){
    this.dataSourceRouting = dataSourceRouting;
    this.env = env;
}
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return dataSourceRouting;
}

@Bean(name = "entityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder
        .dataSource(dataSource())
        .packages("com.zinu.account_manager.model")
        .properties(additionalJpaProperties())
        .build();
}

@Bean(name = "transcationManager")
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Autowired @Qualifier("entityManager") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
}

private Map<String, Object> additionalJpaProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
    properties.put("spring.jpa.generate-ddl", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.generate-ddl"));
    properties.put("spring.jpa.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
    // Add more properties as needed
    return properties;
}
}




@Component
public class DataSourceRouting extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

private ShardZeroConfig shardZeroConfig;
private ShardOneConfig shardOneConfig;
private ShardTwoConfig shardTwoConfig;

public DataSourceRouting(ShardZeroConfig shardZeroConfig,
        ShardOneConfig shardOneConfig, ShardTwoConfig shardTwoConfig) {
    this.shardZeroConfig = shardZeroConfig;
    this.shardOneConfig = shardOneConfig;
    this.shardTwoConfig = shardTwoConfig;

    Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
    dataSourceMap.put(0, shardZeroDataSource());
    dataSourceMap.put(1, shardOneDataSource());
    dataSourceMap.put(2, shardTwoDataSource());
    this.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
    this.setDefaultTargetDataSource(shardZeroDataSource());
    this.afterPropertiesSet();
}

@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
}

public DataSource shardZeroDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(shardZeroConfig.getUrl());
    dataSource.setUsername(shardZeroConfig.getUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(shardZeroConfig.getPassword());
    return dataSource;
}

public DataSource shardOneDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(shardOneConfig.getUrl());
    dataSource.setUsername(shardOneConfig.getUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(shardOneConfig.getPassword());
    return dataSource;
}

public DataSource shardTwoDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(shardTwoConfig.getUrl());
    dataSource.setUsername(shardTwoConfig.getUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(shardTwoConfig.getPassword());
    return dataSource;
}

}

@Configuration
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.shard1")
public class ShardOneConfig {

private String url;
private String password;
private String username;



public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}


}

public class ShardStrategy {

private static final int NUM_SHARD = 3;
public static int calculateShard(String driverId) {
    int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < driverId.length(); i++) {
        hash = 31 * hash + driverId.charAt(i);
    }
    hash = Math.abs(hash);
    return hash % NUM_SHARD;
}

}


@Component
public class TenantContext {

private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();



public static void setCurrentTenant(int tenantId) {
    CONTEXT.set(tenantId);
}

public static Integer getCurrentTenant() {
    return CONTEXT.get();
}

public static void clear() {
    CONTEXT.remove();
}
}



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/drivers")
public class DriverController {

private DriverService driverService;

public DriverController(DriverService driverService, KafkaService kafkaService) {
    this.driverService = driverService;
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Driver> createDriver(@RequestBody Driver driver) {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    driver.setId(uuid.toString());
    int shardId = ShardStrategy.calculateShard(driver.getId());
    TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(shardId);
    driver.setShardId(shardId);
    Driver savedDriver = driverService.saveDriver(driver);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(savedDriver, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Driver> getDriverById(@PathVariable String id) {
    Driver driver = driverService.getDriverById(id);
    if (driver != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(driver, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<Driver>> getAllDrivers() {
    TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(0);
    List<Driver> drivers = driverService.getAllDrivers();
    TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(1);
    List<Driver> drivers1 = driverService.getAllDrivers();
    TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(2);
    List<Driver> drivers2 = driverService.getAllDrivers();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(drivers, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteDriverById(@PathVariable String id) {
    driverService.deleteDriverById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

@PutMapping
public ResponseEntity<Driver> updateDriver(@RequestBody Driver driverRequest) {
    Driver driver = driverService.updateDriver(driverRequest);
    if (driver != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(driver, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

@PutMapping("/update/location")
public ResponseEntity<Driver> updateDriverLocation(@RequestBody UpdateDriverLocationRequest request) {
    Driver driver = driverService.updateDriverLocation(request);
    if (driver != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(driver, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
}

I tried clearing the tenant context but it does not help.
